# Avoid all duplicates with Distinct for writing to the file from list except specific value

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates, distinct

I want do

before writing to the file from list

```
List<string> List = new List<string>();
```

I use distinct to avoid duplicates:

```
IEnumerable<string> sepStr = List.Distinct(); 

foreach (string StrExtractToFile in sepStr) 
{                       
     using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(doc.txt))
           sw.WriteLine(StrExtractToFile);
}
```

but I want avoid all duplicates except word "border." into the file if exist in List, "border." must be passed into the file with duplicates, other duplicates must be avoided.

I'm not sure, what is a proper or correctly to say better way to do it. I not sure if `String.Contains Method` is the way for such case

Comment: does order matter?

Comment: @taquion Hello, yes order is important.  list is updated all the time but order must be saved. and I  write string by string from list to file and same way from file to list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your custom `IEqualityComparer<>` to get the desired behavior:

```
class CustomComparer : EqualityComparer<string>
{
    public override bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == "border" || y == "border") return false;
        return Default.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then, call `Distinct` overload passing an instance of the comparer:

```
SplitContList.Distinct(new CustomComparer());
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
SplitContList.Select((w, i) => new { w, key = w == "border" ? i : 0 })
             .Distinct()
             .Select(x => x.w);
```

Comment: I tried both ways, but it removes border for writing into the file, not sure maybe I'm doing something wrong. I have edited my question  to be more clear

Comment: @nikorio: so you want that duplicates not appears at all? if the list is `a, border, a, b, c, border, c, d` what should be the resulting list?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with Linq, but I would just use a quick loop...

```
List<String> Str = new List<String>();
foreach (string s in SplitContList)
{
    if (s == "Border" || !Str.Contains(s))
        Str.Add(s);
}
```

This add the string to the list if it is "Border" or if it isn't already in the list.

Comment: HI, I have edit  question, because it is not clear enough,  and nothing from given codes works for me

Comment: This loop just filters out the duplicate strings. You can do your stringwriter.append (or anything else you want to do) at the same time you call Str.Add(s);.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var items = new List<String>{"Brett", "James", "James", "Border", "Border", "John"};
    var distincts = items.Where(x => x != "Border").Distinct().ToList();
    var borders = items.Where(x => x == "Border").ToList();
    distincts.Concat(borders).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

Comment: Hello, same result as with other solution, I have edit my question, so maybe it was not clear, check my edit

Comment: You say: 'but I want avoid all duplicates except word "border." into the file if exist in List, "border." must be passed into the file with duplicates, other duplicates must be avoided.'  That is what this does.  It removes duplicates except if they are the word border in a mock up.  I don't know what you really want unless you provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an elegant LINQ-Solution I did not think of, but the classic solution is not that hard to think of either

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach(var s in SplitContList)
{
    if(!results.Contains(s) || s == "border.")
    {
        results.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Paul Kertscher Hello, I have edit my question, seems like it was not quite clear, because nothing from given solutions does not works for me proper way

Answer (score 0):

I go for @Elemental Pete answer just with one change

```
var SplitContList = new List<string>();
        var Str = new List<String>();
        foreach (var s in SplitContList)
            if (s.Equals("border",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)|| !Str.Contains(s))
                Str.Add(s);
```

Just in case you do not matter case

Comment: @djangojazz answer works too but it enumerates twice the list while this (Elemental Pete's) answer does it just once

Comment: Hello, I have edit my question, because it was not clear, so seems like nothing works as I need, or I'm doing something wrong, just check

Answer (score 0):

```
  var filteredList = SplitContList
                      .Where(c => c != "border")
                      .GroupBy(v => v)
                      .Select(group => group.First())
                      .Concat(SplitContList.Where(c => c == "border")).ToList();
```

Comment: I've edit question because seems like it was not clear. Not sure, but nothing work from given solutions correct form me

Comment: @nikorio If a solution does not work downvote, please.

Comment: you can try to describe more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with another collection, that contains the already appended strings and check in the loop.

```
List<string> List = new List<string>();
HashSet<string> alreadyUsed = new HashSet<string>();
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(doc.txt))
{
    foreach (string StrExtractToFile in List)
    {
        if (StrExtractToFile == "border" || !alreadyUsed.Contains(StrExtractToFile))
        {
            alreadyUsed.Add(StrExtractToFile);
            sw.WriteLine(StrExtractToFile);
        }
    }
}
```